# Qt 5.0 including personal header issues

Tags: c++, qt, include

look i'm kind of new to programming in c++ with Qt so i've downloaded the 5.0 version on my win 7 64 bit. i have made a class named Mafenetre and i implemented its code and it seems perfect but when i i try to run the main program it says
C:\Users\Zbart3i\Downloads\Programs\test\main.cpp:3: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Mafenetre.h': No such file or directory

this is my pro code:

```
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mafenetre.cpp

QT+=widgets

HEADERS += \
    mafenetre.h
```

this is code of Mafenetre.h:

```
#ifndef MAFENETRE_H
#define MAFENETRE_H


include <   QtWidgets>

class Mafenetre:public QWidget
{
public:
    Mafenetre();
private:
    QPushButton *m_bouton;

};

#endif // MAFENETRE_H
```

this is Mafenetre's.cpp:

```
#include      "mafenetre.h"

Mafenetre::Mafenetre():QWidget()
{
    setFixedSize(300,150);

    m_bouton=new QPushButton("pimp mon bouton",this);

    m_bouton->setFont(QFont("monotype corsiva",15));
    m_bouton->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);

}
```

and the main.cpp

```
#include<    QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include<    QtWidgets>
#include<    Mafenetre.h>


void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Mafenetre fenetre;


    fenetre.show();
    app.exec();

}
```

Comment: You have "mafenetre.h" in your .pro file, it should be 'Mafenetre.h' (with upper-case M)

Comment: i've changed still the same problem

Comment: Have you installed the visual studio plugin for Qt? try running qmake from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you should use the *#include "name"*, not *#include*  (Quote marks instead of triangle brackets), as they have different meanings.

*#include*  looks in certain directories where libraries (including the standard library) is installed.
*#include "name"* looks first in your project's folders, and then checks the other directories.

Well, to be technically accurate, what folders they look in, and in one order, is compiler-specific.

This:

```
#include <Mafenetre.h>
```

Should be this:

```
#include "Mafenetre.h"
```

Read this:

> [MinGW #include search directories](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/IncludePathHOWTO)
>
> ### Other Directories Searched by Default
>
> The minimal list of directories, identified as described
>   above, specifies the only locations which will be searched by default,
>   for system header files or for headers associated with user installed
>   libraries; however, there is one exception. Astute readers may have
>   noticed that the include file search path is itemised in a pair of
>   sequential lists, with the second being concatenated to the first;
>   however, the first, identified as the #include "..." search list
>   appears to be empty. In reality, this apparent emptiness is possibly
>   misleading; unless the user specifies the "-I-" option when invoking
>   GCC, this list contains exactly one directory: the directory in which
>   the source file containing the #include "file" directive resides.
>
> **Notice that this one additional directory is not searched for headers specified with the `#include <file>` form of the #include directive; it applies only for those headers specified using the `#include "file"` form of the directive.**

And make sure your "Mafenetre.h" file is in the same folder as your main.cpp file. Otherwise you need to do #include "folderPath/fileName.h", and also add the path to the **SOURCES** or **HEADERS** variables in the .pro file.

Also make sure the spelling is identical, and that the proper case is used - sometimes it matters, sometimes it doesn't.

If you are still having trouble, try to compile a simple project consisting of just a single main.cpp, to make sure everything is installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have included the right header. Also i don't see you using the QObject macro in your header file. It should be something like this:

Mafenetre.h:

```
#ifndef MAFENETRE_H
#define MAFENETRE_H

#include <QWidget>

    class Mafenetre : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit Mafenetre(QWidget *parent = 0);

    signals:

    public slots:

    };

    #endif // MAFENETRE_H
```

Mafenetre.cpp:

```
#include "mafenetre.h"

Mafenetre::Mafenetre(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
}
```

Finally you main.cpp should be like this, check the headers:

```
......
#include "mafenetre.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Mafenetre m;
    m.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```